# Powershell: reference class inside and outside module

Tags: powershell, class, using, powershell-module

I'm trying to use classes and reference them within each other. Unfortunately I can't seem to figure it out how. What I try to do is:

- Create a module exporting classes in different files. One of the classes has a method which returns another class.
- Import the module in another class and make use of the classes from the module.

What I tried (simplified example):

Item.ps1

```
class Item {

}
```

ItemList.ps1

```
. '.\Item.ps1' 

class ItemList {
    [Item] function Items () {
    // It goes wrong here. Visual studio code mentions type Item cannot be found.
    }
}
```

Utilities.psm1

```
. '.\Item.ps1'
. '.\ItemList.ps1'
// I'm not sure if this is the right way to export the classes via the module
```

Foo.ps1

```
using module '.\Utilities.psm1'

class Foo {
    [ItemList] function CreateItemList() {
     // It goes wrong here. Visual studio code mentions type ItemList cannot be found.
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if some could help me figure this out!

**Update**

It looks like it can't be done. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/class_newtype) the following is mentioned:

> In this release, you can't use a type literal (for example, [MyClass]) outside the script/module file in which the class is defined.